# Python Easiest Way to Sum List Intersection of List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

Let's say I have the following two lists of tuples

```
myList = [(1, 7), (3, 3), (5, 9)]
otherList = [(2, 4), (3, 5), (5, 2), (7, 8)]

returns => [(1, 7), (2, 4), (3, 8), (5, 11), (7, 8)]
```

I would like to design a merge operation that merges these two lists by checking for any intersections on the first element of the tuple, if there are intersections, add the second elements of each tuple in question (merge the two). After the operation I would like to sort based upon the first element.

I am also posting this because I think its a pretty common problem that has an obvious solution, but I feel that there could be very pythonic solutions to this question ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a dictionary for the result:

```
result = {}
for k, v in my_list + other_list:
    result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v
```

If you want a list of tuples, you can get it via `result.items()`.  The resulting list will be in arbitrary order, but of course you can sort it if desired.

(Note that I renamed your lists to conform with Python's style conventions.)

Comment: Note that `result.items()` will return a `dict_items` object in Python 3. Of course you can always do `list(result.items())`.

Answer (score 4):

Use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
results_dict = defaultdict(int)
results_dict.update(my_list)
for a, b in other_list:
    results_dict[a] += b
results = sorted(results_dict.items())
```

Note: When sorting sequences, `sorted` sorts by the first item in the sequence. If the first elements are the same, then it compares the second element. You can give `sorted` a function to sort by, using the `key` keyword argument:

```
results = sorted(results_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) #sort by the 2nd item
```

or

```
results = sorted(results_dict.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[0])) #sort by absolute value
```

Comment: (+1) I don't know how all this time I didn't realize that `dict.update` accepts a sequence the same as the dict constructor.  Also, it is trivial to sort on the first item of the tuple as requested by the OP (`results = sorted( results_dict.items() )` )

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks! I missed the part about a sorted result. Will edit.

Comment: @mgilson: Apparently `update()` accepting iterables was introduced in 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

A method using itertools:

```
>>> myList = [(1, 7), (3, 3), (5, 9)]
>>> otherList = [(2, 4), (3, 5), (5, 2), (7, 8)]

>>> import itertools
>>> merged = []
>>> for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(myList + otherList), lambda e: e[0]):
...    merged.append((k, sum(e[1] for e in g)))
... 
>>> merged
[(1, 7), (2, 4), (3, 8), (5, 11), (7, 8)]
```

This first concatenates the two lists together and sorts it. [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) returns the elements of the merged list, grouped by the first element of the tuple, so it just sums them up and places it into the merged list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [(k, sum(v for x,v in myList + otherList if k == x)) for k in dict(myList + otherList).keys()]
[(1, 7), (2, 4), (3, 8), (5, 11), (7, 8)]
>>>
```

tested for both Python2.7 and 3.2
`dict(myList + otherList).keys()` returns an iterable containing a set of the keys for the joined lists
`sum(...)` takes 'k' to loop again through the joined list and add up tuple items 'v' where k == x

... but the extra looping adds processing overhead. Using an explicit dictionary as proposed by Sven Marnach avoids it.